# Ubuntu 12.04 Dual Monitor Worked but not Working Now

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using `NVIDIA GT218` and unable to see my monitors in `"Display Settings"`, following info might help

```
# lspci 
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Device 041e (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
```

Primary display is connected on `GT218` which is working but there is no display on `Intel`, interestingly `Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6 (tty displays)` are working on `Intel` but not on `NVIDIA`.

```
# lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218 [GeForce 210]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is blank

`nvidia`-settings does not show both monitors neither `arandr`

```
# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 256mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Currently Second Display (Intel) is just blank and opens tty consoles only.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I've connected both displays to same nVidia card using HDMI to VGA. It works flawless but I had to give up on onboard VGA as primary display. Additionally, Alt+Tab does not work with nVidia being primary display card.